# Last (For Now) Question On Limit Evaluation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

What (if exists) the $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{(n+1)^n-(n-1)^n}{n^n+2}$?

Should I use the binomial theory in the numerator? Please try to keep it as elementary as possible because we are only in the beginning of the course.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try dividing both the numerator and denominator by $n^n$. The numerator will now start with the term$(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$. Does this look familiar?

Comment: Thanks, I got: $\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n-(1-\frac{1}{n})^n}{1+\frac{2}{n^n}}$; is that what you meant? if so does the numerator converge to $e-e^{-1}$? and does the denominator converge to infinity?

Comment: You have the right answer for the numerator, but check your answer for the denominator again.

Comment: Oops, I meant to write that the denominator converges to 1; if I'm correct then the sequence converges to $e-e^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

For simplification, does it help you to consider a general $n$ on the (real) number line? Then adjacent integers can be described as $n-1$ and $n+1$ and we have a sequence of three numbers $n-1, n, n+1$. The difference of the two endpoints $n+1 - (n-1)$ is $2$. What then, happens to the differences for powers of these integers?

Does that aid you in any way?

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: You're not asking the question and I fail to see why you would respond to me.

Comment: Different approaches guys, don't be sol blind sighted into accepting one answer as the only answer.

Comment: Fair enough. Care to explain how your post might help the OP?

Answer (score 0):

For sake of complete answer, this answer will reflect the discussion in the comments of the question.

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(n+1)^n-(n-1)^n}{n^n+2}&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n-\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}{1+\frac{2}{n^n}}\quad\text{(Divide by $n^n$)}\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{e-e^{-1}}{1}\quad\text{(Use $\left(1+\frac{a}{n}\right)^n=e^a$ for numerator)}\\
&=e-e^{-1}
\end{align*}$$